# How can I toggle the value of a variable with a delay?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS code fetches data like this:

```
this.retrieve = function (contentStatusId) {
    $http({
        url: '/api/Content/Retrieve',
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            contentStatusId: contentStatusId,
        }
    }).success(function (result) {
        home.grid.data = angular.copy(result);
    });
};
```

I have a variable called `message` that's attached to the $scope of my app controller.

How could I modify this so that before the retrieve the `message` variable is set to "fetching" **if the retrieve takes more than a second** and when the retrieve returns the `message` variable is immediately set to null?

I would like to do this with some kind of **reusable** function as there are many times I have fetches like this.

Can

Comment: Learn real JS before using APIs like jQuery and Angular:
setTimeout and
setInterval are your friends

Comment: Well... angular is another king of fruit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fy4zMw4BfwgxuHgzXz8n?p=preview).

You can implement a directive that shows the 'fetching' message:

```
app.directive('fetching', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="fetching" ng-if="pending > 0">fetching...</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      scope.pending = 0;

      $rootScope.$on('ShowFetching', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.pending++;
        }, 1000);
      });

      $rootScope.$on('HideFetching', function() {
        scope.pending--;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Which can be used somewhere in your template (outside `ng-view`, if you have any)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <fetching></fetching>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.startFastAjax()">Fast Ajax</button>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.startSlowAjax()">Slow Ajax</button>
</body>
```

Now, when ever you initialize an ajax call, you `$emit` the `'ShowFetching'` event and whenever it completes (success or error), you `$emit` the `'HideFetching'` event. This can be centrally done with an http interceptor (checkout `$http` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)).

The trick is that you increment the `pending` counter with 1 second delay. That means it may be decremented first, but that's ok since the condition to render the message is `pending > 0`.

EDIT:

Since the above example may blink under certain circustances, here is a reworked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CrxX00ssf87NoTnxyBeU?p=preview) that does not do so. In a real application, replace `Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1).toString()` with some king of GUID.

The idea is, before decrementing, check if there is a pending task to do the increment for that particular source (thus, the `requestId`). If yes, cancel the task and do nothing.